# Sonar losing project roles configuration on new analysis

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins and a Sonar server (version 3.4) running on my Server. Every time my Jenkins does a build a Sonar code analysis is triggered using the sonar-maven-plugin 2.0. I set up some custom sonar roles (Settings -> Security -> Roles) for my open source projects, so that anyone can see the results of these. But everytime a new analysis is done, sonar seems to forget this custom defined roles and applies the default ones, so anonymous users can not take a look at the statistics.

I'm running the Sonar analysis using the sonar-maven-plugin 2.0, from within Jenkins.
Does anyone know how to save the custom sonar roles permanently?

**Default Roles:**

Users: sonar-users

Code viewers: sonar-users

**My Custom Roles:**

Users: Anyone, sonar-users

Code viewers:  Anyone, sonar-users

**UPDATE:** Sonar Version 3.4 / "Roles" are defined here:  Settings -> Security -> Roles

[sonar administration panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HHxx.png)
[image: sonar administration panel]

Comment: Which version of Sonar are you using ? When you're talking about "My Custom Roles", I guess you're talking about the content of the 'Roles' administration page available on your open source projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elton, this is in fact a critical bug introduced in Sonar 3.4 : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4050. We're going to fix it and version 3.4.1 should be available next week.

Comment: thanks for creating a ticket! I'll wait until the fix is rolled out!

Comment: seems to be fixed with 3.4.1!